# newline replacement in string using regex

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I'am using the following regex to remove newlines from a string:

```
$description =~ s/\r//;
$description =~ s/\n//;
```

but afterwards I am getting true for:

```
$description =~ m/\n/
```

It seems regex did not replace all newlines from the string, any help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your substitutions are not global substitutions - they replace only the first instance of the pattern in the string. To make a global substitution, add a g after the final slash, like so:

```
$description =~ s/\r//g;
$description =~ s/\n//g;
```

You can also combine the two substitutions into a single substitution using a character set:

```
$description =~ s/[\n\r]//g;
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to remove single chars, use `tr` rather than `s///`.

```
$description =~ tr/\r\n//d;
```

This will remove all occurrences of either `\r` or `\n` regardless of their respective positions in the string.